# spring Transaction exception handling

Tags: spring

Basically with spring Transaction management .We can annotate the service layer class with @Transactional.

Also i have annotated my DAO layer class with @repository to make checked exception to unchecked exception.

Now when a runtimeexception is encoutered by the service layer class it will rollback.

My question how do we go about the exception handling. I will have to put some error message to UI .So i need to capture the exception .

How do i go about it.

Comment: catch it, like any other exception. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: In the service layer class we do not have any exception handling mechanism ? we have just annotated by @transactional (spring rollback catchig the exception ...).How does tnhe spring rethorw the exception and we can handle the exception at the controller class .

Comment: The transactional interceptor catches the exception, rollbacks the transaction if necessary, and rethrows it. So you can catch exceptions in the controller layer.

Comment: I would recommend you to have a global exception handler with @ControllerAdvice to send appropriate message to the client in the case of exception. Reference https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc